# Best practice to store credentials for Marketing Cloud Mobile SDK

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush-android, mobilepush-ios

What would be the best practice to store the credentials such as appId and access token for Marketing Cloud Mobile SDK?
If we hard code it directly inside the app, do you think there is a security issue? I', not sure whether a user can view the source code of app somehow which could be possible for web pages. If yes, I would like to know how we should store the information securely.